# Extracting a row and converting it into column headers

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a table that is staged by a seperate interface and the headers of that file are part of the rows as below:

| ID | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Coln |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | Amt1 | Amt2 | Amt3 | Amt4 | Date |
| 10 | 8.00 | 6.00 | 8.00 | 8.50 | 01/02/2021 |
| 12 | 7.00 | 7.00 | 3.50 | 8.00 | 03/01/2021 |

The columns are dynamically created by the interface so they will be Col1 to Coln, and then staged into this table. So the main goal is to create an rdl report that will display all the records from the table, which always change everytime the interface runs.

I have no way of modifying the interface and so is there a way I can extract that entire row of headers from the table maybe into another table to make those values the column headers and the values as follows:

| ID | Amt1 | Amt2 | Amt3 | Amt4 | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 8.00 | 6.00 | 8.00 | 8.50 | 01/02/2021 |
| 12 | 7.00 | 7.00 | 3.50 | 8.00 | 03/01/2021 |

Or is there a way of displaying this data correctly in the rdl file with the headings dynamically created?

Comment: How do you define which row is the header (remember tables have no inherent ordering)

Comment: Selecting from the table, I have ordered by one of the columns so that the headers become the first/top record

Comment: OK which column? Please be specific otherwise we can't help

Comment: It seems like the *real* problem is your import process and you should be fixing that. In the import process you should be defining your first row is the header row, and then you can use strongly typed column.

Comment: @Charlieface In the actual scenario, the ID for the record I want is blank. so if I order by say Col1, the top record will be the one with the headers. Larnu I am unable to change the import at the moment, so I was looking for an alternative solution for the mean time.

Comment: Are the actual column names fixed though? WIll there always be the same number of columns?

Comment: @Charlie there will not always be the same number of columns. The columns are staged depending on whether there is data. If there is no data the column is skipped and it won’t be in the fb table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must say, this is much easier to do with a reporting tool, but it can be done with dynamic SQL if you want.

**The big complication is the fact that you don't even know how many base columns you have, or what their names are,** so we need to do two dynamic queries: once to get the column name values for the base columns, and again to get the actual values.

Dynamic SQL can be highly confusing, try to keep your head straight about which part is static and which dynamic. Make sure to always use `QUOTENAME(someValue)` for dynamic column names, and `QUOTENAME(someValue , '''')` for dynamic text, this ensures they are correctly escaped.

> I've assumed the row with `ID IS NULL` is the one with the column names

```sql
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max), @cols nvarchar(max);

SET @sql = N'
SELECT @cols = CONCAT_WS('','''
+ (
    SELECT '
,' + CASE WHEN c.name = 'ID' THEN '''ID''' ELSE
      'QUOTENAME(' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ', '''') + ''='' + QUOTENAME(' + QUOTENAME(c.name, '''') + ')'
      END
    FROM sys.columns c
    WHERE c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('YourTable')
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)') + '
)
FROM YourTable t
WHERE ID IS NULL
';

PRINT @sql;  -- for testing

EXEC sp_executesql
  @sql,
  N'@cols nvarchar(max) OUTPUT',
  @cols = @cols OUTPUT;

SET @sql = N'
SELECT ' + @cols + '
FROM YourTable
WHERE ID IS NOT NULL
';

PRINT @sql; -- for testing

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=aa1c1e597234306a9edb904404b41bf9)

Comment: Hi, I’m using SSMS 2016 and does not recognise STRING_AGG as a built in function. What could be the alternative please?

Comment: You'll have to use `FOR XML`, have modified

Answer (score 0):

Write a query that [dynamically unpivots](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3002/use-sql-servers-unpivot-operator-to-dynamically-normalize-output/) the data in the table.

Then use a [matrix report](https://sqlservergeeks.com/sql-server-how-to-handle-dynamic-column-report-in-ssrs/) to dynamically pivot the results for presentation.

Alternatively, if the exact number of columns returned is unknown, but is known to be within some maximum set of possible columns, you could generate a report with all possible columns, then programmatically set column headers (or if all possible column headers are also known in advance, create those statically), and programmatically hide columns in the report that have no data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think this will work after I get the headers correct. Currently the table headers are col1, col2 … and I want the headers to be amt1, amt2 …. From that table record. If I unprovoked the table as it is I will still get col1,col2 instead of the actual headers I need. Don’t know if this makes sense

Comment: But in one of your comments above you said "there will not always be the same number of columns". A "normal" SSRS report can't have a variable number of columns.

Comment: So which means my solution might not work either. I really don’t know how to achieve this that’s why I came here

Comment: Either solution I have given will work. The second way is easier if the column's aren't "truly" dynamic - ie, there's some maximum possible number of columns. The first way works no matter what, even if the columns are completely unpredictable, but is much harder to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Since your ID is NULL for the header row, you can filter this record out of the table data using a FILTER:

```
=IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!ID.Value), 0 , 1)
```

[image]

Then for your header row, you just need to identify the records with a NULL value for each column.

```
=MAX(IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!ID.Value), NOTHING, Fields!Col1.Value))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers, I ended up consolidating most of them but also hard coding the number of columns to 250, it is unlikely to reach that number but it has worked as temporary solution.